# reading binary file leaves some bytes unread

Tags: c++

I have a binary file containing an image whose dimensions are `(1908,1908,3)` without any header. Each pixel is a single byte, so there should be 1908 x 1908 x 3 = 10,921,392 bytes.

I've used the following function to read the file, using iterators.

```
std::unique_ptr<std::vector<char>> SaliencyMapperTester::readImage(std::string filename)
{
    std::ifstream input_testcase(filename,std::ios_base::in|std::ios_base::binary);
    std::unique_ptr<std::vector<char>> vecPtr = std::unique_ptr<std::vector<char>>(new std::vector<char>());
    if (input_testcase.is_open())
        std::copy(std::istream_iterator<char>(input_testcase),std::istream_iterator<char>(),std::back_inserter(*vecPtr));
    return vecPtr;    
}
```

The problem is that the vector actually contains **less** `char`s than there should be.
if, instead I use `input_testcase.read()` and provide the number of bytes to read, I get the correct result. It seems that I'm using `istream_iterator` incorrectly, but I can't tell what's wrong.

What's going on?

Comment: Prefer to use `uint8_t` for bytes.  The `char` type is range based and may be signed or unsigned depending on the compiler settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using [std::istreambuf_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator) to read the file in this manner. This is equivalent to using `read`.

`std::istream_iterator` is equivalent to using the `>>` formatted extraction operator to read from the file. That will not be very useful, in this case.

Comment: ok, I suppose same logic holds for writes too?

Comment: Well, yes, you have ostream_iterator and ostreambuf_iterator. However when writing there's not much of a difference, except that ostreambuf_iterator bypasses all the overhead of `>>`.